# Tests do not run in their separate it{} bock but they run when its inside a single it{} block

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

Just started testing with cypress and I am unable to understand why tests do not run in their separate block like this

```
    it('Validate that user is able to navigate to PDP of a product from PLP', () => {
    cy.xpath("//div[@class='collectionGrid__products']").xpath("//p[normalize-space()='Flight / Pre Workout']").click({force: true})
});

it('Validate that user is able to add product to cart by clicking ADD TO CART CTA button', () => {
    cy.get('.add-to-cart-btn > .button').click({force: true})
});

it('Validate that user is able to close cart drawer by clicking "x" button on top right of cart drawer', () => {
    cy.get('.sidebar__headerClose').click()
});

it('Validate that user is able to open cart drawer by clicking cart button on navbar', () => {
    cy.get('.header-extra__cartAnchor').click()
});

it('Validate that user is able to decrease product count using product quantity spinner', () => {
    cy.get('[aria-label="decrease quantity for Flight / Pre Workout"]').click()
});
```

But it works as a single test/functional scenario when I club them together like this

```
    it('Validate that user is able to navigate to SUPPLEMENT category PLP from navbar', () => {
    cy.visit("https://www.bareperformancenutrition.com")
    cy.get('.js-mega-menu > .nav__menu-link').click()
    cy.xpath("//div[@class='collectionGrid__products']").xpath("//p[normalize-space()='Flight / Pre Workout']").click({force: true})
    cy.get('.add-to-cart-btn > .button').click({force: true})
    cy.get('.sidebar__headerClose').click()
    cy.get('.header-extra__cartAnchor').click()
    cy.get('[aria-label="decrease quantity for Flight / Pre Workout"]').click()
    cy.get('.sidebar__headerClose').click()
});
```

Can I get help on this? This is really bothering me as this is throwing error as its unable to find the element.

Comment: Are the `it()` blocks within a `describe()` or `context()` block?

Comment: @agoff Its inside a describe() block

Comment: When you say "tests do not run", do you mean the tests do not execute at all? They don't execute as expected? Do they all fail?

Comment: @agoff Everything inside separate it blocks fail and the common error is 'unable to find the element' but when clubbed together it passes

Comment: `it()` blocks are not meant to be test steps, but entire tests. If you're splitting each individual action into it's own `it()` block, the test will fail because state is cleared between each `it()` block. Check out Codecademy's cheatsheet on mocha `it()`/`describe()` blocks: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/fscp-test-driven-development-with-javascript/modules/fecp-write-good-tests-with-mocha/cheatsheet

Answer (score 3):

A "test" is technically an `it()` function call, but you can use them as granular as you like.

There is nothing wrong with creating individual `it()` functions if you want to have descriptions for each step.

You just have make sure the page is in the correct state for each call.

For example, you can set up the page in a `beforeEach()` hook, something like

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit("https://www.bareperformancenutrition.com")
})

context('with empty cart', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.get('.js-mega-menu > .nav__menu-link').click()  // open cart
  })

  it('Validate that user is able to navigate to PDP of a product from PLP', () => {
    cy.xpath("...").xpath("...").click()
  })

  it('Validate that user is able to add product to cart...', () => {
    ...
  })

})

context('with items in cart', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.get('.js-mega-menu > .nav__menu-link').click()  
    cy.xpath("...").xpath("...").click()
  })

  it('Validate that user is able to decrease product count using product quantity 
  spinner', () => {
    ...
  })
})
```